# xamarin shrinkable toobar like youtube app

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, animation

hi everyone im trying to maken shrinkable toobar simular to the one that youtube app has.
i have been searching all over the internet for days and this is the closest thing i found to what i am looking for [click here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/collapsing-toolbar-animation-your-xamarinforms-app-alon-rom/)

[image]

but as you can see its not the same.
in youtube the effect happens the moment you start scroling  up or down and you can control it unlike here you can't control it.

i attached one sample image of what i am trying to achieve here it is

[image]

so is there anyone who can help me to achieve such a thing thanks in advance?

**this my xml page**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  x:Class="bashal.Views.chatPage"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:bashal.ViewModels" 
             Title="home" >
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:chatPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
        
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Navy"
      x:Name="DashboardBarGrid"
      RowSpacing="0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="90" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"  
                         Margin="10,10,10,0"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">


                <Image HeightRequest="32"
                       Source="recept.png"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start" />


                <Image HeightRequest="32"
                       Source="settings.png"
                       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />


            </StackLayout>


            <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Red"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">


                <Image x:Name="MainImage"
                       HeightRequest="90"
                       Source="user.png" />


            </Grid>


            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Black"
                         Margin="10,0,10,0"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">


                <Label HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       FontSize="14"
                       TextColor="White"
                       Text="Welcome" />


                <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                       FontSize="14"
                       TextColor="White"
                       Text="2009/1/1" />


            </StackLayout>


        </Grid>
        <ScrollView Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled">
            <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding rooms}" >
            
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                        
                </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**and this is the code behind**

```
public partial class chatPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly double _initialImageScale;
        private Animation _firstRowAnimation;
        private Animation _middleRowAnimation;
        private Animation _lastRowAnimation;
        private readonly double _initialFirstRowHeight;
        private readonly double _initialMiddleRowHeight;
        private readonly double _initialLastRowHeight;
        private readonly RowDefinition _firstRowDefinition;
        private readonly RowDefinition _middleRowDefinition;
        private readonly RowDefinition _lastRowDefinition;

        private bool _isScrolled;

        public chatPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

            _initialImageScale = MainImage.Scale;

            _firstRowDefinition = DashboardBarGrid.RowDefinitions[0];
            _initialFirstRowHeight = _firstRowDefinition.Height.Value;

            _middleRowDefinition = DashboardBarGrid.RowDefinitions[1];
            _initialMiddleRowHeight = _firstRowDefinition.Height.Value;

            _lastRowDefinition = DashboardBarGrid.RowDefinitions[2];
            _initialLastRowHeight = _lastRowDefinition.Height.Value;
           
        }

        

        private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollView = (ScrollView)sender;

            // Move back to original height
            if (_isScrolled && (int)scrollView.ScrollY == 0 &&
                _firstRowDefinition?.Height.Value < _initialFirstRowHeight &&
                _lastRowDefinition?.Height.Value < _initialLastRowHeight)
            {
                scrollView.IsEnabled = false;

                _firstRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _firstRowDefinition.Height = new
                GridLength(d.Clamp(0, double.MaxValue)),
                _firstRowDefinition.Height.Value, _initialFirstRowHeight, Easing.Linear, ()
                => _firstRowAnimation = null);
                _firstRowAnimation.Commit(this, "first row animation", 16, 500);

                MainImage.ScaleTo(_initialImageScale, 500, Easing.Linear);

                _middleRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _middleRowDefinition.Height = new
                GridLength(d.Clamp(90, double.MaxValue)),
                _middleRowDefinition.Height.Value, _initialMiddleRowHeight, Easing.Linear,
                () => _middleRowAnimation = null);
                _middleRowAnimation.Commit(this, "middle row animation", 16, 500);

                _lastRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _lastRowDefinition.Height = new
                 GridLength(d.Clamp(0, double.MaxValue)),
                 _lastRowDefinition.Height.Value, _initialLastRowHeight, Easing.Linear, ()
                 => _lastRowAnimation = null);
                _lastRowAnimation.Commit(this, "last row animation", 16, 500,
                Easing.Linear, (v, c) =>
                {
                    _isScrolled = false;
                    scrollView.IsEnabled = true;
                });
            }
            // Hide the rows
            else if (!_isScrolled && _firstRowDefinition?.Height.Value >=
                     _initialFirstRowHeight && _lastRowDefinition?.Height.Value >=
                     _initialLastRowHeight)
            {
                scrollView.IsEnabled = false;

                _firstRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _firstRowDefinition.Height = new
                GridLength(d.Clamp(0, double.MaxValue)),
                _initialFirstRowHeight, 0, Easing.Linear, () => _firstRowAnimation = null);
                _firstRowAnimation.Commit(this, "first row animation", 16, 500);

                MainImage.ScaleTo(_initialImageScale * 0.7, 500, Easing.Linear);

                _middleRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _middleRowDefinition.Height =
                new GridLength(d.Clamp(65, double.MaxValue)),
                _middleRowDefinition.Height.Value, _initialMiddleRowHeight, Easing.Linear,
                () => _middleRowAnimation = null);
                _middleRowAnimation.Commit(this, "middle row animation", 16, 500);

                _lastRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _lastRowDefinition.Height = new
                GridLength(d.Clamp(0, double.MaxValue)),
                _initialLastRowHeight, 0, Easing.Linear, () => _lastRowAnimation = null);
                _lastRowAnimation.Commit(this, "last row animation", 16, 500,
                Easing.Linear, (v, c) =>
                {
                    _isScrolled = true;
                    scrollView.IsEnabled = true;
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `in youtube the effect happens the moment you start scroling up or down and you can control it `  Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're saying about the effect, can you elaborate on your requirement or upload a short video to better illustrate your requirement?

Comment: bro if you have youtube app on your phone you can simply open it and scrol up and down and see what happens to the toolbar that is exactly what i'm trying to apply